# Getting Null Pointer Exception in Sqlitedatabase.query method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sqliteopenhelper

I know this is a pre-asked question. But still I am not able to find solutions.
I am opening a database with a SQLiteOpenHelper and applying insert and query method in SQLiteDatabase object.
But I am getting NullPointerException in query method --
Here is my openhelper class:

```
public class MovieDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movie.db";
    public MovieDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
           String create_mov_table = "CREATE TABLE" + "MOVIE" + "(" +
                                    "mov_id"  +  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                   "mov_pos"  +  " BLOB);";
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create_mov_table);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        // should be your top priority before modifying this method.
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "MOVIE");

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

Here is my utility class in which I am applying methods --

```
public class utility extends ActionBarActivity {
   static Context c ;
    // convert from bitmap to
    // byte array
   static SQLiteDatabase db;
    public void onCreate(){

        utility.c = getApplicationContext();
        MovieDbHelper mhelper = new MovieDbHelper(c);

         db = mhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return utility.c;
    }


    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
    public static void addEntry( byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {

        ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();

        cv.put("mov_pos",   image);
        db.insert( "MOVIE", null, cv );
    }
    public static Cursor getEntry(String[] columns){
        return db.query("MOVIE",columns,null,null,null,null,null);  **--  nullpointer** 
    }

}
```

I execute:

```
Cursor cup;
 String[] cm = {"mov_pos"};
            cup = utility.getEntry(cm);  **-- null pointer**
```

Comment: Are you sure the db isn't null? When do you initialize this variable? (And why is this class extends Activity?)

Comment: Yes , first time database is null  and I m unable to get context without extending activity

Comment: So you need to initialize your db variable somewhere....

Comment: All the methods in your utility class can be put in the Helper class, I believe.

Comment: @Roi   but I don't want to initialize any varibale because I don't want to get any dummy data

Comment: @haint   what is the benifit to that??

Comment: what is the benefit of creating another class AND extends ActionBarActivity? if you want the context then it's available in the Helper class already.

Comment: @haint  but I want to get rid off null pointer

Comment: if you won't initialize db somewhere, you will get null pointer exception...

Comment: Copy and paste your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call a static method from a class that extends `Activity`, the `onCreate` method of that class is obviously not called, that's why you are getting NPE.

Firstly move all your methods in the utility class to your MovieDbHelper class, and use the `context` provided in the constructor.

```
public class MovieDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movie.db";

    public MovieDbHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         this.context = context;
    }
}
```

for example your `getEntry` (put it in the `MovieDbHelper`) can be rewritten as:

```
public Cursor getEntry(String[] columns){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.query("MOVIE",columns,null,null,null,null,null);  **--  nullpointer** 
}
```

EDITED:

usage in your activity:

```
MovieDbHelper helper = new MovieDbHelper(YourActivityName.this);
String[] cm = {"mov_pos"};
Cursor c = helper.getEntry(cm);
```

usage in your fragment:

```
MovieDbHelper helper = new MovieDbHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
String[] cm = {"mov_pos"};
Cursor c = helper.getEntry(cm);
```

EDIT 2:

```
public addEntry( byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();

    cv.put("mov_pos",   image);

    try {
        db.insertOrThrow("MOVIE", null, cv );
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same databse for getentry and addentry so is it necessary to declare the database outside the two methods.

Comment: what? you don't seem to understand how `SQLiteOpenHelper` works at all. It's the same database no matter how many times you initialise `MovieDbHelper`. If the db is already created then it will not call `onCreate`, you know?

Comment: ok 
but now it is giving null pointer at SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: Have you put it in `MovieDbHelper`?

Comment: it's the error log that says NullPointerException. Just copy it and paste into http://pastebin.com/ then link it here.

Comment: but why do you using your DB in the adapter? It should be in the Activity

Comment: now it is giving  Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'  
as I am using this in ImageAdapter which uses Baseadapter

Comment: paste the whole content of your ImageAdapter on pastebin and I will modify it

Comment: ya now it worked.But I jst want to know how did u do this ??

Comment: just look at the constructor of the `MovieDbHelper`. It takes `Context` as a parameter. I simply assigned it in your code, where you have the `mContext` ready to use.

Comment: I am trying to build an app as given in  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gtXUu1nzLGWrGfVCD6tEA0YHoYA9UNyT2yByqjJemp8/pub?embedded=true

So as soon as I proceed I am getting another error

Comment: Cursor c = mdb.getEntry(cm);
            c.moveToFirst();
            byte[] image = c.getBlob(position); --  error   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0


this is my project on git  - https://github.com/gol197/Popular_Movies_14CE10032_GSC.git

Comment: there's no data in your table, add some before getting.

Comment: I want to get it according logic.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the add method. I can only help you with the syntax, I can't give you the logic.

Comment: If u have some time please look at the whole project.

Comment: Sorry but I can't. That's all I could help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249254/unable-to-access-changed-value-of-variable-from-another-class-in-android-studio
Have a look at this question