# Unable to access changed value of variable from another class in android studio

Tags: java, android, static

I have created two class one is LoginSignupActivity.java and another is ProfileActivity.java

LoginSignUpActivity.java---

```
        public class LoginSignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

          **  static string id;     **
            public void getUserDetailsFromFB() {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    try{
                                    **    id=response.getJSONObject().getString("id");**
            }
catch (JSONException e) {
                            //If anything goes wrong
                            Log.e("my",e.toString());
                        }
            })
            }
            }
            }
```

ProfileActivity.java ---

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dp);
        if(imageView!=null){

               **  String fbid = (new LoginSignupActivity).getUserDetailsFromFB().id;    **
            if(fbid!=null){
                 Glide.with(this).load("http://graph.facebook.com/1615242245409408/picture?type=large").into(imageView);
                //Glide.with(this).load("http://graph.facebook.com/" + "1675239799409652" + "/picture?type=large").into(imageView);
                Log.d("mayank", LoginSignupActivity.id);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("mayank","null facebook id");
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("mayank","null image view");
        }
}
}
```

When I access id inside ProfileActivity.java 
it shows null value.
I want to access that value that is obtained inside LoginSignupActivity.java.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Where's your exception block? Is it missing from this page? Are you eating it?

Comment: @WalterM
now I have edited

Comment: Does the exception get thrown? Can you confirm that id for sure is not null immediately after calling `response.getJSONObject().getString("id")`?

Comment: Ya I have printed there

Comment: Ya i have printed there
id id not null after calling

Comment: `getUserDetailsFromFB()` returns `void`, so I don't know how it even compiles. Format the code it's impossible to read. Also `(new LoginSignupActivity)` doesn't make any sense. post the actual code. that compiles. And post logcat error.

Comment: 12-13 14:13:18.301 5776-5776/com.example.anshu.cognitio D/mayank: null facebook id
It is giving null facebook id

Comment: check answer below and find your problem

Comment: @WalterM
Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252258/getdrawable-gives-null-object-while-trying-to-get-bitmap-from-imageview

Answer (score 0):

Try to make id public and I think you should get it throw `LoginSignUpActivity.id`

If the login is for one time only I recommand you to use SharedPreference.

Comment: I have made it public
and wrote String fbid =  LoginSignupActivity.id;
But it is still giving null value 
I want changed value that is changed inside that method

Comment: So use the [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) It's the best way.

Comment: but I will get the same probleim in sharedpreference
I will initialize sharedpreference same as id 
and put value inside the method 
But when I will call sharedpreference from ProfileActivity it will give same value as id 
I want value that is obtained after calling response.getJSONObject().getString("id");

Comment: Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252258/getdrawable-gives-null-object-while-trying-to-get-bitmap-from-imageview

Answer (score 0):

do as:

```
public static  String id="NA";
```

- Use **String** instead of string.
  [Android Studio "cannot resolve symbol String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445233/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-string)
- List item

you will get NA if id is not received by your line of code:

```
  id=response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
```

As you told in comment, you should use the value of id after getting it only

```
 id=response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
```

I thing you should only start the ProfileActivity.java just after getting id valueas below:

```
id=response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
Intent intent=new Intent(LoginSignupActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Ya it is giving NA 
but when I print id just after id=response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
it gives correct id that I need in profileactivity 
I need that value

Comment: you're getting value later, after delay, i'm updating answer soon.

Comment: check answer updated should help, and use String, thanks and let me know

Comment: I don't want to start the activity at that time

Comment: You have to use the value of id after fetching. Otherwise it can't be possible to use value before fetching.

Comment: I have also tried to use image view jst after fetching the id.
But image view is getting null there that means I am not able to inflate that layout in which image view is situated because that layout is associated with ProfileActivity. 
Is it possible to use image view there

Comment: yes you can do, even without the glide library and use the normal method with bitmap, search google

Comment: Ya but when I try to get imageview in LoginSignupActivity it returns null view

Comment: Have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252258/getdrawable-gives-null-object-while-trying-to-get-bitmap-from-imageview